# How to set cookies client-side taking into account Intelligent Tracking Protection?

Tags: javascript, cookies

According to [this blog post on webkit.org](https://webkit.org/blog/8613/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-1/), cookies set client-side using document.cookie are capped to a 7 day expiry.

I understand the rationale behind using `httpOnly` for sensitive cookies such as auth tokens, but if I need to store something for a long duration and have it available across subdomains of a site, then cookies are the only option, right?

With these new ITP restrictions, setting cookies client-side which should live for any longer duration of time is not going to work, so what's the best way to approach this? One idea was make a route which takes params and converts them into a `Set-Cookie` header and then make a request to that instead of using document.cookie. Is there a better way?

Answer (score -1):

One attempt would be to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of cookies, technically they don't expire. The Problem however can be, that the user can decide to empty the localStorage.

Here's an example

```
//use this if you only need it for the current page and remove it after leaving the page
const exampleStorage = window.localStorage;
exampleStorage.setItem('currentUser', 'Manuel');

//use this if you need to keep it even after leaving the page
localStorage.setItem('glob_currentUser', 'Max');

//and finally this if you need to keep it only for the session
sessionStorage.setItem("session", "Morning")
```

If you need more Information about LocalStorage here are 2 helpful websites:

[MDN Window​.local​Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

[The W3C Specification for localStorage](https://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)

Comment: localStorage isn't shared across subdomains, which would be a problem in my case, but also it can't be read server-side.

Comment: yes thats indeed a problem, however you make me wonder, if you have a back-end server, why don't you just save the "cookie-data" for each user on your server?

Comment: The event which leads to a cookie being set happens client-side, and I wanted to avoid having to make a route just to handle setting a cookie due to ITP when nothing needs to happen server-side in relation to that cookie.

Comment: Uff, ye i get what you mean, i know a similar case where a business had problems with ITP messing with their first-party-cookies, they ended up saving the cookie-data in the user-profile on the server. 
The only other way, although i highly discourage using i know of is, saving the data directly on the client maschine. By using the Window.requestFilesystem(...) API, however this is just in draft, and not safe in any way.